# Linking Excel to Access - Headers don't update when a column in excel is added/deleted

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've done a simple link from excel to access. However, the file in excel changes frequently, and columns are added and removed occasionally. What I have noticed is that the headers in access don't change. If I delete a column in excel, the corresponding header in Access is still there. Same problem when I insert a column. A new column doesn't appear with a header - blank cells appear in an already existing column header, and all the values are shifted to the right.

How can I create through VBA or through Access's settings, a setup where the columns are dynamically changed whenever Excel changes?

Thanks for any assistance.

Images:

[Example of Excel file pre-column B deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fpsv.png)

[Example of Access file pre-column B deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEqCd.png)

[Example of Excel file post-column B deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfd5z.png)

[Example of Access file post-column B deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q7eh.png)

For some reason, even though I've deleted column B in excel, the "column B" header still appears in Access, with the column C values underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you originally link a table, Access stores its structure (its "meta data") in the TableDef object for the linked table. This structure is not updated unless you tell Access to do so.

- Manually:

> External Data -> **Linked Table Manager**
>
> Then tick the table(s) that need updating and click OK.

http://theitservice.co.uk/microsoft-access-basics-manage-linked-tables/

- Programmatically:

```vb
CurrentDb.TableDefs("myLinkedTable").RefreshLink
```

If your Excel file changes often enough, you could simply run this command from your startup code (AutoExec macro), so the TableDef is always up to date when you run your DB.

To automatically determine when this is actually needed, would be much more involved (and too broad for this question).

Comment: Ok fantastic, that seems to have done the trick! Thank you so much, the first trick worked!

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second, so you want to export data from Excel to Access but the field names will change in both places?  Here is a simple way to export data data, but I'm not sure how you will handle those changing field names.

```
Sub ADOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, r As Long
    ' connect to the Access database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " & _
        "Data Source=C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb;"
    ' open a recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "TableName", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable  
    ' all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("A" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("B" & r).Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("C" & r).Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Normally, you open an Access Table and then edit the table to change field names.  You can use SQL to create a table dynamically.

```
CREATE TABLE tblCustomers  
    (CustomerID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    [Last Name] TEXT(50) NOT NULL, 
    [First Name] TEXT(50) NOT NULL, 
    Phone TEXT(10), 
    Email TEXT(50))
```

You can use VBA to create a table too.

```
Sub CreateTableX1() 
    Dim dbs As Database 
    ' Modify this line to include the path to Northwind 
    ' on your computer. 
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb") 
    ' Create a table with two text fields. 
    dbs.Execute "CREATE TABLE ThisTable " _ 
        & "(FirstName CHAR, LastName CHAR);" 
    dbs.Close 
End Sub
```

I'm not sure what your setup looks like, and I'm not sure I can suggest some kind of best practice here, but maybe with the ideas I posted here, you can come up with something.  Please do post back with your final solution when you get everything working.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! I'm still new to VBA - how exactly do I integrate this into Access?

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I misread your original post.  I just re-read it and revised my original solution.  I hope this helps you out now.

Comment: oh gosh thanks for all the assistance. I think we might have misunderstood each other - I've attached images of the problem now - that should make things clearer. Thanks regardless for all your help, no worries if you can't add more!

Comment: Hey, just wanted to let you know that my query has been answered in the end! Thanks for all the suggestions, can't thank you enough!

Comment: Ahhh!  Linked Tables!  Gotta love it!!